# Sencha Touch 2 app with more than one proxy

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have two Store. Each associated with a Model. The first store has a proxy to read data from a php file and I need the second Store read data from another php file.

Can I develop an application in Sencha Touch 2 with more than one proxy?

Comment: Yes, you can define a proxy in each store. I often used it and it is no problem

Answer (score 1):

each store can very well have its own proxy but if its just different target php you can tweak url to point to whichever php you want. Please remember response data should be similar because it will use same model for all URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved the problem.

ThinkFloyd, you're right. But I needed to have two Store because charge different data, and I need to associate each Store to a different Model.

My problem was that my second Ajax Proxy didn't load data. I solved the problem by adding an Id to each Proxy.

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        id: 'proxyId',
        url: 'http://.../read.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
```